# SwiftUI macOS extrem lagging window on resize

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am building a macOS app in SwiftUI and I am struggling with a little bug. I have a `ScrollView` with a custom row. I am experiencing a very lagging window on resize with that ScrollView and I do not know why. In the custom row I am using some rectangles and I think that is causing the error. Am I doing something wrong?

This is my main view with the ScrollView:

```
struct CalendarLag: View {
    var body: some View {

        VStack
        {
            ScrollView(content: {
                ForEach(0..<100) { number in
                    HStack
                    {
                        CalendarRow()
                    }.frame(height: 50)
                }.id(UUID())
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This is my custom row:

```
struct CalendarRow: View
{
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: 0)
        {
            Button(action: {
            })
            {
                VStack(spacing: 0)
                {
                    ZStack(alignment: .center)
                    {
                        Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: 66, height: 20)
                                                
                        Text("A")
                        .colorMultiply(Color.white)
                        .padding(.top, 2)
                        .zIndex(6)
                    }
                    
                    ZStack(alignment: .center)
                    {
                        Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 66, height: 46)
                        
                        Text("B")
                        .colorMultiply(Color.black)
                        .padding(0)
                        .padding(.top, 4)
                        .zIndex(6)
                    }
                }
                .mask(Rectangle()
                .cornerRadius(3.0)
                .frame(width: 66, height: 66)
                )

            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .padding(.trailing, 8)
                
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0)
            {
                Text("invoice_detail_start")
                  .padding(.bottom, 4)
                Text("invoice_detail_end_pm")
                  .padding(.bottom, 4)
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is because ScrollView does not have *view reuse* so on window resize it rebuilds all content. I would recommend to use List (or Lazy*Stack since SwiftUI 2.0).

Comment: Even List did not seem to make a major improvement.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for your comment. Indeed, List seems to improve it. So basically I can always use List. What is the advantage of ScrollView then?